# Using new iOS 10 API in compiled framework under XCode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, compatibility

My company is developing an iOS SDK, which uses the new CallKit APIs. The SDK (.framework) is compiled with XCode 8 / SDK 10.0.
However, some of out customers are still using XCode 7 - When I try to integrate our SDK under a XCode 7 project, I got the following error :

```
ld: framework not found CallKit for architecture arm64
```

However, I put some macro directive into the SDK code, to provide a CoreTelephony fallback, but event with this trick, the project's target does not compile with the message above.

Here is the directive example :

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_10_0
@import CallKit;
#endif
```

Do you have a trick to use a SDK compiled with iOS 10 API working under XCode 7 ?

**EDIT**

Find a way to manage that. The idea is to lazy load CallKit (runtime). I had to call performSelector instead of calling directly methods.

Here is some code :

```
    // Lazy load CallKit framework to keep compatibility for XCode 7 SDK integration
    if ([[AppKit sharedInstance] systemVersion] >= kIosSystemVersion10) {
        NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/Frameworks/CallKit.framework"];
        _isCallKitFrameworkLoaded = [b load];
    }

    if (_isCallKitFrameworkLoaded) {
        SEL callObserverDelegate = NSSelectorFromString(@"setDelegate:queue:");
        if ([_callObserver respondsToSelector:callObserverDelegate]) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
            [_callObserver performSelector:callObserverDelegate withObject:self withObject:(__bridge id)(_callObserverQueue)];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
        }
    } else {
        // CoreTelephony fallback
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) is available from iOS 10 and later. Xcode 7 support upto iOS 9 only. If you need to use this framework, you need to update to latest Xcode(obviously Xcode8) which supports iOS 10.

So users who are having iOS 10 only can use this feature and not iOS 9.

Comment: I know that, maybe I poorly explained the issue. The framework is already compiled, under XCode 8 (static library .a). But our customers who integrates our SDK (still compiled under XCode 8) are using XCode 7. The first solution would be to compile 2 frameworks, one for iOS 10, and one for iOS 9. But this is not ideal, I would like to know if I can put some macros before building our SDK.- to avoid generating two static librairies.